# Famo.us: Performance of famo.us application is not same in all android phones

Tags: javascript, android, famo.us

I have created a famo.us application having different modules. When .apk file installed to phones, different limitations came into scene are as follows-

1. RenderController 3d animation ara not running in .apk while smoothly running in browsers like chrome(even if the persective is set to 1000).
2. .apk file working in phones having android version 4.4.4("motoG") but not in other phones having "Jelly bean"(version 4.2.0 or 4.2.2)
3. If background-color is set with class name in apk, then in apk that surface is not showing background-color, but showing in browsers when running file locally.

Like above so many issues I am facing. Is there any proper way to solve this?

Thanks.